# get $stateParams of child page where parent page has no parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, angular-ui, state

i am having trouble understand how does $stateParams work. I am able to call the $stateParams service on the parent page. But when i create a child page (using the same controller) for it and call the $stateParams i got a empty object. I also notice that the $statePrams will refer to the parent page (even though there is no parameters), which is why i am getting an empty object.

Here is the code for my app.js:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider
    .otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
    .state('home', 
        {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: './js/views/tableTmpl.html',
            controller: 'tableCtrl'
        })
    .state('home.dashboard', 
        {
            url: '/dashboard/:id',
            templateUrl: './js/views/tableTmpl.html',
            controller: 'tableCtrl'
    });
```

Here is the code for the controller:

```
app.controller('tableCtrl', function($scope, tableService, uiGridConstants, $stateParams){
console.log($stateParams);   //getting empty object
console.log($stateParams.id); //getting undefined, this is because the object is empty
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: tell me why you have assigned same controller to parent and child state?

Comment: That's a good question. It's just because they are sharing the same function/method. In general, is that a bad code design (architecturally)?

Comment: Yes...that is very bad design... parent state controller should have general functionality and child controller will have special functionality which can only relate to child only

Comment: Alright. Thanks @PankajParkar. I will make take changes and see if it works. So technically, if i separate the page then it should work? (A.K.A. the issue is because i am using the same controller)

Comment: No this is not an issue..try this suggested thing and comeback here..if you still find any issue